# asp.net mvc4 cross domain session lost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, dns, area

I'm creating a new web application using ASP.net MVC4

our application web site runs on 2 doamin names www.domain1.com & www.domain2.com

since there are lots of common controllers/view i implemented Areas that are bound to the domain

```
public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "NS1";
            }
        }
        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
            "NS1_default", "{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
            new { hostname = new areaRedirect("www.domain1.com") }
        ).DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = true;
        }
```

And for domain2

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
        "NS2_default", "{controller}/{action}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
        new { hostname = new areaRedirect("www.domain1.com") }
        ).DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = true;
    }
```

This works fine and does everything i need BUT..

when i switch from one area to the other i loose my logged in session.

is there a way to stay logged in? the account controller is common to both areas.

so basically same app, same server just that my namespace happens to be a domain name

instead of seeing www.somedomain/domain1/action we get www.domain1/action

Thanks for your time